# GUI MMS - a graphical monero multisig app

Tags: development, multisig

We all know Monero Multisig is still a work in progress and most online guides are quite tricky to follow for the average user. A relatively promising project is the *Multisig Messaging System* (MMS) leveraging *PyBitmessage* to create a secure communication channel across multiple signers.

However, while turning out to be an excellent tool, it is quite unused as it doesn't solve the main issue, *usability*.
Would it be possible to perform all the process automatically?

Imagine a GUI app where the user clicks a button to create a wallet, exchanges the addresses with other signers, pastes inputs in the GUI app and then the rest is done in background.
MMS isn't accessible from Monero RPC so I guess the GUI app would need to integrate the static wallet library somehow and talk to PyBitmessage.

Answer (score 5):

> Would it be possible to perform all the process automatically?

Not completely automatic no. Any UI would still need to prompt for user confirmations for example.

> Imagine a GUI app where ... and then the rest is done in background. MMS isn't accessible from Monero RPC so I guess the GUI app would need to integrate the static wallet library somehow and talk to PyBitmessage.

MMS *is* [supported](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#prepare_multisig) in the wallet RPC so anyone wanting to create a more user friendly experience could absolutely make use of the wallet RPC to do so. The Monero GUI uses the wallet library, so can use the MMS functions directly.

I suspect the main reason it's not exposed in the GUI is simply to do with the dependance on PyBitmessage. Whatever the reason, as far as I'm aware there's no technical roadblock preventing it being added, rather it just requires someone to care enough about MMS in the GUI to add it there.

Comment: The only reference I can find in Monero RPC source code to MMS is in wallet2.h *mms::message_store& get_message_store() { return m_message_store; }; const mms::message_store& get_message_store() const { return m_message_store; }; mms::multisig_wallet_state get_multisig_wallet_state() const;*

Comment: Multisig, which is exposed in the RPC, uses MMS, which is part of wallet2. There are a *lot* more references to "mms" than what you have found! I suspect you're searching on GitHub (which excludes large files).

Comment: I can't invoke any MMS command via RPC, I tried "mms", "mms init", etc. I was referring to RPC calls mentioning MMS, apparently it is not possible to invoke mms commands from an external third party interacting to *monero-wallet-rpc*

Comment: Here's the disconnect, you want to use MMS directly, but it's used under the hood by the multisig command's, which are what are exposed -- it doesn't need talking to directly.

Comment: I need to run mms commands automatically, how would you do it?